# onError call back in websockets

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, websocket

I am trying to find out what all errors are raised and under what circumstances by browsers when dealing with a websocket server. I couldn't find any specification mentioning this. Are these error events browser specific? (I hope not, though I am mainly concentrating on Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/ and search for 'exception'. Should be pretty complete.

Comment: Unfortunately after viewing that very page, a google search led me here.  The page mentions that certain errors should be thrown, but it does not specify that any of them should trigger the onerror event, and it doesn't say anything about the onerror event at all, and certainly not what parameters it takes or what their types are (Error? ErrorEvent?) and furthermore each of the error mentioned do not define anything about them such as what properties they have.  It should be complete, but it's not at all.

Comment: Even Microsoft's own documentation for the events lists none of their parameters.  I know the onmessage event has at least a data property on its event parameter, but msdn just says it's a Function and gives no signature, let alone info about any of the parameters it takes. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772757(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yeah? Is the answer on that page? No its actually not.